# Vue.js video this.$refs[something].play() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I'm receiving several video urls using axios and add them to video 
Object. Vue is getting videos okay and I can play with no problems. However, when I'm trying to play it using $refs, it is not working...

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(video, index) in videos" v-bind:key="video">
        <video
            controls
            v-show="videoState[index]"
            :ref="index" :src="video ? video : sampleVideo"
            type='video/mp4'>
        </video>

        <div class="video-btn" v-bind:class="{ flash: buttonFlash }"
                    v-show="videoState[index]"  
                    @click="recordStart(index)">
             <img src="../../assets/microphone.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    methods: {
        recordStart(video) {
            this.$refs[video].play();
        },
    },
},
```

If more information is needed, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

[Edited]

I added recordStart(index) call.

And this is the log of this.$refs object.
[image]

**[Solved]**

changing it to `this.$refs[video][0].play()` worked. My bad :(.

Comment: Please show the call to `recordStart(video)`. Since `:ref="index"`, the parameter must be an integer.

Comment: Do you get an error (e.g. cannot find play on undefined) or an exception (NotAllowedError or NotSupportedError)? If you log `this.$refs` in `recordStart` with a `debugger` statement behind it to stop code execution, what do you see in that object?

Comment: actually, the index is not Integer, let me try if it works with integer @RichardMatsen

Comment: That should work - the `ref` is defined in the template and is set to `index` which comes from the `v-for` as an integer.

Comment: Alternatively you can set `ref="video"`, should be ok if `video` is a string.